# Vue.js and Laravel passing json data

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have been working on building a simple table that gets its data from a mongodb database that is being queried for the json data and not the data needs to be passed to the vue component on the frontend but I am unable to understand how the json data is transferred from laravel to vue. To understand the code here is what I have done so far:

api.php route:

```
Route::middleware('api')->group(function () {
Route::resource('/home', [ProductController::class,'home']);
});
```

web.php route:

```
Route::get('/home', [PostController::class,'home']);
```

PostController Home method:

```
public function home() {
    $posts = Post::paginate(4);

    return response()->json($posts);
}
```

Home component:

```html
<template>
<div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Id</td>
                <td>Title</td>
                <td>Status</td>
            </tr>
         <tr v-for="El in results" v-bind:key="El.id" >
             <td>{{El.id}}</td>
            <td>{{El.STATUS}}</td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        
</div>
</template>

<script>

export default{
     data() {
        return {
            results: []
        };
    },
    methods: {
        fetch() {
            axios.get('/api/home')
                .then(response => this.results = response.data)
                .catch(error => console.log(error));
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Home.blade.php

```html
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
         
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Data</div>
                     
                <div class="card-body">
                  <home-component></home-component>
                </div>
                 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

All of this seems fine but when I run the code it just show the json and does not render any of the vue component. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your question? Your vue script (frontend javascript) calls an URL which points to your server, which returns a JSON response which your vue script can directly use.

Comment: Yeah so it seems like all of it should work right? But when I go to /home route it just shows the json data.

Comment: Ah gotcha, ive posted an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `/home` URL both as a data endpoint and an HTML endpoint. What you should do is design it something like this:

```
Route: GET /api/home
Returns: JSON data
Code: `return response()->json(...);`

Route:: GET /home
Returns: HTML data with javascript that requests /api/home
Code: `return view('home');`
```

Both routes are ordinary http requests, but one only serves JSON data and the other one serves HTML data to be interpreted by your browser.

Comment: I tried what you said and I get an error saying` ErrorException
Array to string conversion ` why is that I am not sure where I am converting array to string? also I have updated the question to include the new api route which I added

Comment: Also as a side note I am assuming something is wrong with how I am retrieving and reading the data as when I load the web page without the /api/home in the vue component all the table titles and table headings load in properly

Comment: Sorry I didnt get a notification for your comment. It's a bit hard for me to debug your errors like this; the first one is pretty much as it says: somewhere you are trying to print/output an array (probably in your view?). Just look at the error message where it points to. If it points to a weird file like `327xn23jk....php`, then its pointing to a compiled view file. In that case, look at the correct line in `storage/framework/views/327xn23jk....php`.

Comment: Hi thank you fro your comment but I have actually moved on from here and I am currently working on a different problem but thank you for trying to help